# How to default image to fit/fill when you upload in Filepond?

Tags: javascript, angular, image, filepond, pintura

I'm using the filepond library in my Angular project and I was wondering if anybody knew if it was possible to set an image to fit/fill by default when a user uploads?

Im not very familiar with filepond and Pintura but I've looked through some documentation and didn't see anything about this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think a plugin can help: [Image resize plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/plugins/image-resize/)

How to add plugins with angular-filepond?

```
import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from 'angular-filepond';
 
// Registering plugins
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from 'filepond-plugin-file-validate-type/dist/filepond-plugin-file-validate-type.esm';
registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileValidateType);
 
// Adding FilePond to imports
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FilePond
  ]
})
 
export class AppModule { }
```

Here are some infos from the plugins page:

> The Image resize plugin automatically calculates and adds resize information.

> The Image preview plugin uses this information to show the correct preview. The Image transform plugin uses this information to transform the image before uploading it to the server.

The picture shows some properties. `imageResizeMode` sounds useful I think.

[image]